# Angular2 and Typescript development tools

Tags: typescript, angular

I am very new to development using Angular2 and Typescript . Can anyone suggest some of the best development tools which has autocomplete and debugging facility.
I am already aware of debugging in chrome so please don't mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keen on this one - https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/
...but it requires license

Or this one for free - https://code.visualstudio.com/

But a lot of people adore something like Atom

Answer (score 0):

I use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/b?utm_expid=101350005-24.YOq70TI1QcW9kAbMwmhePg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F), for my work with Angular2 and TypeScript. It has the requested features you're looking for. It works pretty smoothly with the [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) from Angular's tutorial. There is also [Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) that will work as well. I haven't used it though, so I'm not sure what additional setup steps would be required.

Comment: Dan - Refer this if you want to setup Angular2 in VS2015 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html